# Does it matter if brake calipers are different or cheaper brand?

Tags: brakes

My rear left caliper has gone.  I just need to replace the rear left caliper and brake pad since others are ok.

I don't know what brand the existing calipers are, probably stock though.  Is it ok to fix an aftermarket rear caliper(id imagine they're the same size and shape even if poor quality) or might there be problems?

Comment: I would be wary of replacing caliper with a non-stock aftermarket variant on only one side, just in case the aftermarket variant is slightly different. If it's replaced with an identical variant only on one side, apparently it's ok: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/19238/change-calipers-on-both-sides

Answer (score 2):

If you get one that is re-manufactured or made to OEM specifications, you should be alright.

Replace the rotor and pads on both sides at the same time, if you can. This will help keep the wear balanced. In the long run it will be worth it.

Might be worth taking the old one with you so you make sure you get an exact match from the store.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you buy from a reputable dealer and make sure to get the right caliper for your vehicle, it should be fine. Personally I probably wouldn't choose the *cheapest* brand if there's more than one option, but really you should be fine with anything you get at your typical Pep Boys, NAPA, Advance Auto Parts, AutoZone, etc.

Like others have said though, it's recommended to replace pads (and arguably rotors) in pairs (eg, both sides at the same time). Depending on much material is left on the rotors, you may be able to just have one or both resurfaced ("turned") at a machine shop. Then again, rotors aren't usually *too* expensive, so if you want to err on the side of safety, consider replacing them both if even one is questionable.